# JavaScript Canvas sprite animation speed

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a problem with canvas animation. I'm working with [this tutorial](http://mrbool.com/html5-canvas-moving-a-character-with-sprites/26239). 
It's quite simple, but now I want to make animation with 60 fps. I tried `setInterval(Update, 1000/60)`, and of course it's working but now there is a problem with the sprite. Its animation is too fast. Is there any way to make 60fps and slow down the character sprite animation (to look more natural) ?

I'm sorry that I don't have live example, but it's a little bit hard to create one without ftp for sprites.

**the code:**

```
var canvas;
var ctx;
var dx = 10;
var x = 30;
var y = 0;
var WIDTH = 1000;
var HEIGHT = 340;
var tile1 = new Image ();
var posicao = 0;
var NUM_POSICOES = 3;

    function KeyDown(e){
        switch (e.keyCode) {
            case 39: 
                if (x + dx < WIDTH){
                    x += dx;
                    posicao++;
                    if(posicao == NUM_POSICOES)
                        posicao = 1;
                }
                break;   
        case 37:
            if (x + dx < WIDTH){
                    x -= dx;
                    posicao++;
                    if(posicao == NUM_POSICOES)
                        posicao = 1;
                }

        }
    }
    function KeyUp(e){
        posicao = 0;
    }
    function Draw() {   
        tile1.src = posicao+".png";
        ctx.drawImage(tile1, x, y);
    }
    function LimparTela() {
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(233,233,233)";   
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();   
    }
    function Update() {
        LimparTela();   
        Draw();
    }
    function Start() {
        canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        return setInterval(Update, 1000/60);
    }
        window.addEventListener('keydown', KeyDown);
        window.addEventListener('keyup', KeyUp);
Start();
```

Comment: you can always add more frames to the sprite

Comment: Please show us at least your code (or the relevant parts of it), it is fine without a live demo.

Comment: you can always show a sprite in more than one frame, but it won't look as smooth.

Comment: Ok, that's not a bad idea. With 1000/60 animation is so fast, that adding more than one frame, won't make the sprite animation look so bad after all. But I'm not sure how to do this. There is posicao++ variable that makes iteration for all sprites. I will try to add some code soon.

Comment: @Bergi I added some code.

Comment: Is `posicao` the frame number in your sprite sheet? I don't really understand, I had expected an animation (not changing pics onkeydown/up)

Comment: @Bergi You have 4 sprites (0.png, 1.png .... 4.png), they are changing after keydown. I know it's a bad example (imo better do one sprite and move its position, like in this tutorial: http://www.onlywebpro.com/2012/10/05/animating-sprites-in-html5-canvas/ ) but I think it will be the same way to resolve this problem (tell me if I'm wrong). And I don't understand what do you mean "I had expected an animation". I don't think there is another way to make an animated character.

Comment: Yes, that's what your code does… but the sprite changes have nothing to do with your `setInterval`-framerate (which is what I had expected from a continous animation)?

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea, a simple fix you could try adding extra frames to the spritesheet? This will also improve your animation without worrying about breaking something else :)

Answer (score 1):

**You can "throttle" the Update() to execute less often.**

```
var counter=5;

function Update() {
    if(--counter>0){ return; };
    LimparTela();   
    Draw();
    counter=5;
}
```

**If the user presses a key you can force the animation by setting the counter to 0.**

```
function KeyDown(e){
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 39: 
            if (x + dx < WIDTH){
                x += dx;
                posicao++;
                if(posicao == NUM_POSICOES)
                    posicao = 1;
            }
            // zero the counter to force the animation now
            counter=0;
            break;   
    case 37:
        if (x + dx < WIDTH){
                x -= dx;
                posicao++;
                if(posicao == NUM_POSICOES)
                    posicao = 1;
            }
            // zero the counter to force the animation now
        counter=0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you move your sprite, you should divide the number of pixels moved by the number of frames per second.  For instance, if you want to move him `dx` pixels per second at 60fps, define `var fps = 60;` as a global variable and do `x += dx/fps;` when you move him.  What was the frame rate before?  30fps or something?  Whatever it was, if you want it to go the same speed as before at 60fps, make your `dx` equal to however many pixels it traveled per second by multiplying your previous `dx` by the fps.  So if it was moving at 10px per frame at 30fps, make `var dx = 300;`.